# Calling a method in custom view

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

I am creating a simple drawing app with a custom view that draws lines on the screen.  I am calling a method in my custom view .m file from my viewcontroller file.  I've got it set up so it autocompletes my method, which means that it knows it exists, but isn't firing.

In my custom View BezierSigCapView.m

```
- (void)erase {
    path = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
    [pointsArray removeAllObjects];
    [self setNeedsDisplay];
    NSLog(@"ERASE!");
}
```

In my View Controller.h file

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) BezierSigCapView *myView;
```

In my View Controller.m file

```
/// in viewDidLoad
BezierSigCapView *theView = [[BezierSigCapView alloc] init];
self.myView = theView;

/// my button code
- (IBAction)ClearButton:(UIBarButtonItem *)sender {
    [self.myView erase];
    NSLog(@"Should Erase");
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you're step into `clearButton`?

Comment: You haven't in your code up here, but have you added the IBAction prototype declared in the ViewController.h file?
And have you associated the button to this action in Interface Builder?

Comment: Can you explain me why this BezierSigCapView *theView = [[BezierSigCapView alloc] init];
self.myView = theView;   Why you created thView? if you can use self.myView throught the class??

Comment: It does not matter wether the IBAction is declared in the interface or in the implemetation only. The key question is whether it is connected prperly - which I doubt.

Comment: Aparently you create "myView" programmatically. Why do you use a weak reference here? Shoudn't it be strong in this case? This is not directly related to your issue but could cause the very next issue that comes up.

Comment: @KuramaYoko It is no longer necessary to declare IBAction in the header file, it can be declared solely in the implementation. This is arguably better since the header file should expose as little as possible about the implementation.

Comment: Yes, I see "Should Erase" in my log and the button is hooked up.

Comment: Shouldn't you be setting frame for this view using `- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@hermann pointed me in the right direction.  I was creating the view programmatically and in interface builder.  I deleted the view that I created programmatically and hooked up an Outlet to the view on interface builder as a property.  I also got rid of "theView" which was redundant.

```
//In view controller.h file
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet BezierSigCapView *myView;

//In view controller.m file
//in the implementation
@synthesize myView;

//I also removed the code below from the view controller.m file that was causing another issue
self.myView = [[BezierSigCapView alloc] init];
```

Answer (score 0):

Kindly check if you have connected the `- (IBAction)ClearButton:(UIBarButtonItem *)sender;`
 to the button.

Comment: Then kindly check if self.myView is initilised or not, nslog it.